# R xts sum multiple subjects

Tags: r, sum, multiple-columns, xts

I have dataset, including 4 columns: Date, Source Actor (3 main actors, coded A, B, C), Target Actor (4 main actors, coded D, E, F, G), Action (5 types of actions, coded from 0 to 4). I want to sum the total number of each types of actions for each Source actor - Target actor combination by Date. For example:

> ```
> Date       SourceActor    Target Actor  Action   Freq
>
> 1-1-2011   A               E            0       
> 1-1-2011   B               G            1        
> 2-1-2011   A               F            4
> ```

I tried xts but it counts all the number of actions by Date, regardless of Source Actor and Target Actor, so that I cannot get the total number of Action for each Source Actor-Target Actor combination. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the `r` tag we request that you share data using `dput()` especially for anything involving dates or time series, as it preserves class information and facilitates reproducibility. You can hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info. Also, you seem to have 4 columns but 5 headers.

Comment: If you just want to compute the sum of `Action` for each triplet `(Date, SourceActor, TargetActor)`, you can use `dplyr`. Assuming that your data is in a data frame `df`, this is: `result <- df %>% group_by(Date, SourceActor, TargetActor) %>% summarise(Freq = sum(Action))`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have non-numeric data in an `xts` object as an `xts` is *always* a matrix (and hence of 'same types for all columns') and an index vector.

So here your date become a ... less useful character matrix.

I would suggest using `data.table`.